# @font-face and letter-spacing in webkit

Tags: fonts, cross-browser, webkit, embedding, font-face

I just discovered that letter-spacing doesn't always work in webkit (and perhaps other browsers?) when embedding fonts.  I've tried it on two different fonts and received different results.

"League Gothic Regular" will work

http://www.theleagueofmoveabletype.com/fonts/7-league-gothic

"Quicksand Light" will not

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand

What's the skinny?  Is there a way to force the hand of non-compliant fonts?

Quick note: Firefox does seem to apply to both fonts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I have the answer but I was having a word-spacing problem with League Gothic from Font Squirrel, I couldn't figure it out until I re-generated the font-face stuff on the site using different settings. I use the Paul Irish's Bulletproof method...

[Font Squirrel settings http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/8784/screenshot20100428at132.png](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/8784/screenshot20100428at132.png)

Comment: Yes, I use Paul's bullet proof method (I actually use a variant, the one over @ css3please.com), but maybe I could try this route again and see if a more meticulous approach helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I was able to clear it up using this code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'League Gothic';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/league_gothic-webfont-webfont.eot');
    src: local('‚ò∫'),
            url(data:font/woff;charset=utf-8;base64,/* base64-encoded font here */) format('woff'),
            url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,/* base64-encoded font here */) format('truetype'),
            url('/assets/fonts/league_gothic-webfont-webfont.svg#webfontu5sqNtGI') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This was mostly generated from [FontSquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) and then modified slightly (I removed the local() stuff and substituted the junk characters).

This cleared up my letter-spacing issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is caused only by svg fonts!!!
I wasn't able to verify it strictly but my test cases prove that much.

Reorder your font-face urls putting svg format last, it should fix the problem. But svg fonts won't get used and rendering might be dirty(er)