# letter-spacing does not work on mobile browsers only desktop

Tags: css

I'm using sizes in "REM" and to my surprise the letter-spacing is not working in mobile browsers, Android and iOS. Desktop Work Fine.

CSS

```
#header{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: initial;
}

#header h1{
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 12rem;
 right: 3rem;
 margin: 0;
 text-shadow: 0 4px #570b0b;
 letter-spacing: -0.7rem; /* Work Only Desktop */
}
```

desktop:
[image]

mobile:
[image]

Comment: Not reproducible on Android 4. Please provide complete code (HTML and CSS) for reproducing the problem and identify the browsers and platforms tested. If you are using a downloadable font, check whether this is essential and if it is, identify the origin of the font.

Comment: Did you resolved this?

Comment: Have this been resolved? With HTML5 ads booming at the moment, it's imperative that ads look the same in both mobile and desktop - and this will hinder that.

Answer (score 1):

Try `word-spacing` ...though I always use ems:

```
#header h1{
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 12rem;
 right: 3rem;
 margin: 0;
 text-shadow: 0 4px #570b0b;
 letter-spacing: -0.7rem; /* Work Only Desktop */
 word-spacing: -0.7rem;
}
```

***UPDATE**:

I see your using a webfont check this and see if its useful:

[Webkit, letter-spacing issues with webfonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913305/webkit-letter-spacing-issues-with-webfonts)

The only other answer for you is:

- Change REMs to EMs and test
- Web font - make sure you have svg last

Comment: thanks for replying, I think the problem would be to use "REM" I put an absurd amount as: letter-spacing: -10rem; and had no change.

Comment: but why font-size work with REM and letter-spacing not ?

Comment: Why would `word-spacing` affect `letter-spacing`?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela well it seems the real issue has to do with his REM...I think it has to do with the web font too