# Safari font-face letter spacing

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

So after weeks of troubleshooting I found this presents the best fonts in all browsers :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'GothamBook';
src: url('../fonts/gotham-book-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/gotham-book-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/gotham-book-webfont.svg#gotham_bookregular') format('svg'),
     url('../fonts/gotham-book-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/gotham-book-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

However, since the preferred font for most browsers is now `SVG` Safari seems to have trouble handling `letter-spacing` (as in - it just ignores it), however Chrome does not. So i can't see it being a Webkit issue.

Putting SVG to the bottom of the list makes chrome use another format over it, resulting in really bad rendering with no anti aliasing so that's why i prefer using SVG.

So is there any way to either resolve the issue of Safari ignoring SVG font letter-spacing or rearranging the font source list so that SVG is still used in Chrome but Safari will use something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690815/font-face-and-letter-spacing-in-webkit

Comment: Hi that post is outdated, and i already tried messing with the Kerning. But thanks.

Comment: What letter-spacing are you referring to?

Comment: The CSS instruction, letter-spacing. Example : "letter-spacing: 1px;"